# Can I pass arguments in the method of the class for comparing the string from user with the predefined input..?

Tags: java

I am learning OOPS concept in java , during the implementation of Multi-level Inheritance , I had encountered a different output rather than expected output .

I was trying to print the car's name serial no ,brand name and its type but I had encountered an output that is different from the expected output as "M3 "  giving the input as "M3 ".

My program :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Cars
{
   static int Id = 2320 ;
   public void serialNo()
   {
       System.out.println("The serial no. is : "+Id);
   }
}
class Brands extends Cars
{
    static String str1="BMW";
    public void brandName()
    {
        System.out.println("The brand name of the car is :"+str1);
    }
}
class Varients extends Brands
{
    //return method 
    public String typeName(String da)
    {
        String no = " This is not a M3 or M5 car";
        String ba=null;
        String str1="M3",str2="M5";
        if(da==str1)
        {
            ba=da;
            return ba;
        }
        else if(da==str2)
        {
            ba=da;
            return ba;
        }
        else
        {
            return no;
        }
    }
    
}
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public class MultiLevelInheritance {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Varients obj = new Varients();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Car Type");
        String da=sc.nextLine();
        obj.serialNo();
        obj.brandName();
        System.out.println("The series of the vehicle is : "+obj.typeName(da));
        
    }


}
enter image description here

the image shows the output of my program , and I really need to know why my code is running like this in detail.
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are asking. But, you should see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), as comparing reference types with `==` and `!=` tests if they are the *same objects*, and is a likely to result in bugs in your code

Answer (score 0):

In Java the `==` operation when used between two strings it means comparing their address.
You should use `equals` instead to compare string value.